# Toggle between tabs (Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm writing a bot on C# and WebDriver and when it switches between browser tabs with

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(Browser.WindowHandles[1])
```

the browser window unfolds. I think this is a bad property for a bot - to interfere with the user, so I would like that the code switch to another tab without visual effects or at least without browser window unfolds. 
Maybe someone came across this? 
Browser:Chrome

Maybe I'm not so saying, but
browser window unfolds=Bring the browser window to the foreground (on top of all windows)

Comment: What does *the browser window unfolds* mean?

Comment: If you want some help you need to provide more information as @rene requested. We have no idea what you mean by *unfolds*

Comment: Bring the browser window to the foreground (on top of all windows)

Comment: I doubt you can fix this. Maybe this works if you put the browser window on a new desktop but I never tried if this works or if it is even possible,

Comment: @rene That becomes worse. The new desktop becomes active.

Comment: @GoldMiner Did you file a bug report?